# What's a good one device solution for mowing a small lawn?

Tags: lawn-mower, mowing

I recently moved into a new place which includes a very small, maybe 20 square metres, lawn with a terrace.

I'm now wondering what I should get for mowing it. I would really prefer a solution which only requires me to buy one device.

The lawn is essentially a small rectangular area, bounded by a terrace, a garden fence of the neighbours, and a hedge row.

Right now I'm mostly thinking about getting either a manual push mower, or a weed whacker. I'm not an expert when it comes to gardening, but I did a bit of readup now. I think a push mower is the better option for clearing the fully accessible areas, but I think it might fall flat in the areas where the neighbours fence is located. A string trimmer on the other hand is perfect for the corners, but I am unsure whether it is a good fit for the open space, also because the clean cut is very dependent on whether I can keep a steady hand I think.

What would your recommendation be?

Answer (score 1):

String trimmer. I have a situation similar to yours where I have some bee hives. I have tried both a small mower and battery electric string trimmer in the area and now use the trimmer exclusively. Quiet, easy to store, inexpensive, reliable, minimal maintenance, neighbour friendly, easy to navigate obstacles.

The technique to achieve a smooth cut is easy to acquire. Since the machine is quiet and light you quickly develop a semicircular swing like using a scythe, keeping the cutting head an inch or two above the ground. Where the grass is particularly thick you can cut a narrower width.

Comment: Shortly after we moved into our first house, I was trimming the edges of our tiny back lawn with my Stihl professional strimmer. Next think there was a crack and the patio door full length window had shattered into a zillion pieces. The strimmer cord had catapulted a tiny piece of gravel into the glass. £200.00 to replace the window glass. I've never used my strimmer in the garden again.

Comment: @colin Thanks! How big is the area you are cutting with it, and how quick are you done with it? Can you recommend a model as well?

Comment: 20 m^2, 20 min, low end Li-ion.